# price column in dollar and dinar

Tags: mysql, floating-point, currency

I have a price column which maybe include 100.00 which is in dollar or 100.000 which is in Iraqi dinar .
I can't use decimal(10,3) or decimal (10,2) because it is not fixed
 Please, how can I do that ?

Comment: What's stopping you from using DECIMAL(10,3)?

Comment: Are you possibly mixing up decimal point notations? Do you really have a coin which represents 1/1000 Dinar?

Comment: I am so sorry for this mistake . it is one hundred dollars and zero cents and one hundred thousand dinar 100,000

Answer (score 0):

Two question: is it "one hundred dollars and zero cents" and "one hundred dinars and 0 thousandths"?

Assuming this is correct (i.e. you need 2 spaces after the decimal point for dollars, and 3 for dinars), have you considered storing everything as integers and provide conversion to cents/thousandths when displaying only?

Usually currency (even with fractional values) is stored as integers because float values are prone to rounding errors. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency?rq=1), for example, or [just look for "represent currency" here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=represent%20currency).

Comment: it is one hundred dollars and zero cents and one hundred thousand dinar 100,000

Comment: Then you have two different problems. First of all, it should be "100.00" Dollars and "100'000" Dinars, or some other notation to be sure you don't confuse users. Anyway I suggest you represent this as a fairly large integer, plus a "currency code" and provide either a view (if you want to solve this at the DB level) or a formatting function in your application.